# Linking a new Helper File in CakePhp 3 via Composer

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php

I am using Cake PHP 3, and under the `src` folder, I created a new folder called `Helper` and created a new file inside it. And now I went to composer.json and added the required file key inside the autoload. You can see it below:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src"
    },
    "files": [
        "./src/Helper/general_helper.php"
    ]
}
```

But after, doing `composer dump-autoload`, getting `require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/project_name/vendor/composer/../../src/Helper/general_helper.php):`

Its not under the `vendor` folder, I think that's why its giving the error. Any idea, how to solve this issue, cause I want to maintain a separate folder. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use the proper PSR-4 naming style?

Comment: @ndm I don't know how to do it. Can you please explain? Thanks

Comment: **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html#file-and-class-name-conventions** | **http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/**

Comment: @ndm It is a simple php file, in which I will write functions and not using class. So, Is there any way to link the file via composer.json?

Comment: Well I don't see anything wrong with what you're showing, the path points to what you're describing.

Comment: @ndm Yes, but it gives the error that file not found. Completely clueless, how to solve it.

Comment: Well, there's not much I can tell you, other than make sure that the file exists, that the naming is correct, and that the files permissions allow PHP to access the file.

Comment: @ndm Hmm. /opt/lampp/htdocs/project_name/vendor/composer/ It says project_name and then vendor and composer, however, if we can make it project_name, then it will work, cause then it will find src. Any way to do that?

Comment: @ndm The file name was wrong. Solved it. Thanks.